# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing a mobile app with Cordova and Angular JS. My app is on an easyphp localhost.
I use Angular Routes with a ng view directive in my index.html. And I've got this :

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined**

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.status = "Accueil";
}])
.controller('ViewCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('mobile.php/getAnnonces/limit=10')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.posts = data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          // log error
    });
}])
...
```

If I test the URL my script returns JSON (with json_encode). Where am I wrong ?

Thanks for your help,

Regards

Comment: in ViewCtrl, you forgot to pass the depencendy `$http` as a string before passing it as an argument

Answer (score 37):

try to change

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.status = "Accueil";
}])
.controller('ViewCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('mobile.php/getAnnonces/limit=10')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.posts = data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          // log error
    });
}]);
```

Changes:
Passing `$http` service to controller as string so that will resolve at runtime.

Comment: It would be helpful to point out what you changed and why (namely adding '$http').

Comment: You should make your changes more explicit.  What was missing here is '$http' in the dependencies array of ViewCtrl

Comment: If I add the same, still I'm getting the same error "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined".Need your help on this.