# Detailed Heart Rate Export from Jawbone Up4

Tags: jawbone

I'm a researcher trying to do research on stress using the Jawbone Up4. For the research I'm doing I'm looking at stress changes during the day in response to specific stimuli, so I need the detailed hourly heart rate readings.

How can I export the detailed hourly heart rate readings from a Jawbone Up4? I'll be exporting for about 30 people, and the experiment will be running for 4 months and at the moment it looks like my only option is actually sitting down and reading it off the application and entering it manually into a spreadsheet, which is just stupid and impractically time-consuming.

Options I have checked:

1. The historical data offered on the Jawbone website here (https://jawbone.com/support/articles/000011483/historical-data) has insufficient detail - it just gives daily high and low heart rate.
2. The thread here ([Jawbone JavaScript and Resting Heart Rate data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748142/jawbone-javascript-and-resting-heart-rate-data)) seems unresolved - and is a bit over my head.

Option X: If there's no way to get this data out then can someone please recommend a similar device (or devices) from which I can export the hourly heart rate data.

Answer (score 0):

Jawbone does not make all of the heartrate readings available through the [public API.](http://developer.jawbone.com)

However, if you're willing to provide some details about your research, you can request access to this data at research@jawbone.com